# How to implement AND logic in Z3Py

Tags: python, z3, smt, z3py, sat

I want to implement a constraint which requires AND logic in Z3Py. Suppose we have two variables `a` and `b`, I just want to add one constraint which requires `a == 0` and `b == 1`. There should be several ways which can do this in Z3, like `s.add(a == 0, b == 0)` or `s.add(And(a==0, b==0)`. However, I tried one method which is `s.add(a == 0 and b == 0)`. This method doesn't work, the code is:

```
from z3 import *

a = Int('a')
b = Int('b')

s = Solver()

#s.add(a == 0, b ==1)
#s.add(And(a == 0, b == 1))
s.add(a == 0 and b == 1)

print(s.check())
print(s.model())
```

The output of this file is `a = 0`, which means b is ignored... Can someone explain why does this happen? It seems `And(a == 0, b == 1)` and `a == 0 and b == 1` are different in Z3Py.

Comment: On my system `a == 0` is ignored and `b == 1` is retained. I tested this by conjoining an unsatisfiable constraint. `And()` is clearly a `z3` -defined function which joins together terms. It doesn't look like `and` is overloaded within `z3py` library for the same purpose, though I could have missed it in the docs. If this is the case, then `and` is the regular logical operator of `python`.. why it behaves this way I could not say, though.

Comment: Yes, Python does not allow overloading for some operators. Also the "and" operator doesn't return a Boolean value, but the last value that was evaluated; see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not

Comment: If you want an AND logic, so you're doing Boolean algebra. Why then creating integer variables... from a string?